# JavaScript Alert Box for Asking Same Q

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an alert box for when a user inputs the same question twice in a row, it displays an alert box. So when someone ask, "Will my day be good?" twice in a row, an alert box will display. If they ask a new question, it'll be fine. When they go back to asking "Will my day be good?", it should display a new answer again. I've been trying for a few hours now and I'm not sure why it's not working.

```js
//Create an array for you responses. Remember, it's [0-14].
var responses = [
    "Ask again later...",
    "Yes",
    "No",
    "It appears to be so.",
    "Reply is hazy, please try again.",
    "Yes, definitely.",
    "What is it you really want to know?",
    "Outlook is good.",
    "My sources say no.",
    "Signs point to yes.",
    "Don't count on it!",
    "Cannot predict now.",
    "As I see it, yes.",
    "Better not tell you now.",
    "Concentrate and ask again."
]

//Create a variable for your user's input or question.
var question;

//Create a variable if user already asked this question.
var alreadyAsked = [];

//
var validQuestion = false;

//Display the output when user.
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){

    question = document.getElementsByName("askme")[0].value;
    answer = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];

    //If the question has already been asked, display the appropriate alert.
    if (alreadyAsked.length >= 1 && alreadyAsked.indexOf(question) == alreadyAsked.length-1){
        validQuestion = true;
        alert("You've already asked that.");
    } 
    //If the question doe not contain a "?", display the appropriate alert.
    else if (question.indexOf("?") == -1){
        alert("It appears that you aren't asking me a question.");
    }
    //If all goes well, then the question will be answered.
    else{
        if (validQuestion){
            alreadyAsked.splice(-1, 1);
        }
        else{
            alreadyAsked.push(question);
        }
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
    }

};
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
    <p>What would you like to know?</p>

    <input type="text" name="askme" placeholder="Enter a question...">
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="submit">Ask the 8 Ball</button>

    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="images/8ball.png" alt="https://pixabay.com/p-25774/?no_redirect">
    <br />

    <h2>The 8 Ball says:</h2>
    <p id="answer"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: It appears alreadyAsked[] becomes empty every time. So make it global so it will hold values and should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just keep pushing the questions to array as you are trying to do but compare the current question with the last saved question only using
`alreadyAsked[alreadyAsked.length-1] === question`

```html
<div id="container">

<h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
<p>What would you like to know?</p>

<input type="text" name="askme" placeholder="Enter a question...">
<br />
<br />
<button id="submit">Ask the 8 Ball</button>

<br />
<br />
<img src="images/8ball.png" alt="https://pixabay.com/p-25774/?no_redirect">
<br />

<h2>The 8 Ball says:</h2>
<p id="answer"></p>

<script>

    //Create an array for you responses. Remember, it's [0-14].
    var responses = [
        "Ask again later...",
        "Yes",
        "No",
        "It appears to be so.",
        "Reply is hazy, please try again.",
        "Yes, definitely.",
        "What is it you really want to know?",
        "Outlook is good.",
        "My sources say no.",
        "Signs point to yes.",
        "Don't count on it!",
        "Cannot predict now.",
        "As I see it, yes.",
        "Better not tell you now.",
        "Concentrate and ask again."
    ]

    //Create a variable for your user's input or question.
    var question;

    //Create a variable if user already asked this question.
    var alreadyAsked = [];

    //
    var validQuestion = false;

    //Display the output when user.
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){

        question = document.getElementsByName("askme")[0].value;
        answer = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];

        //If the question has already been asked, display the appropriate alert.
        if (alreadyAsked.length >= 1 && alreadyAsked[alreadyAsked.length-1] === question){
            validQuestion = true;
            alert("You've already asked that.");
        } 
        //If the question doe not contain a "?", display the appropriate alert.
        else if (question.indexOf("?") == -1){
            alert("It appears that you aren't asking me a question.");
        }
        //If all goes well, then the question will be answered.
        else{
            alreadyAsked.push(question);
            
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
        }

    };

</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

1. Get the question from the `input`.
2. Check whether the question contains a ? sign.Show alert if not.
3. Check whether it's the same question as previous.Display alert if so.
4. If the question is valid and not same as previous, then set this question as previous (so that you can verify next question against it), populate answer.

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
    <p>What would you like to know?</p>
    <input type="text" name="askme" placeholder="Enter a question...">
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="submit">Ask the 8 Ball</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="images/8ball.png" alt="https://pixabay.com/p-25774/?no_redirect">
    <br />
    <h2>The 8 Ball says:</h2>
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <script>
    //Create an array for you responses. Remember, it's [0-14].
    var responses = [
        "Ask again later...",
        "Yes",
        "No",
        "It appears to be so.",
        "Reply is hazy, please try again.",
        "Yes, definitely.",
        "What is it you really want to know?",
        "Outlook is good.",
        "My sources say no.",
        "Signs point to yes.",
        "Don't count on it!",
        "Cannot predict now.",
        "As I see it, yes.",
        "Better not tell you now.",
        "Concentrate and ask again."
    ]

    //Create a variable for your user's input or question.
    var question;

    //Create a variable to store previous question
    var previousQuestion = null;

    //Display the output when user.
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

        question = document.getElementsByName("askme")[0].value;

        //If the question doe not contain a "?", display the appropriate alert.
        if (question.indexOf("?") == -1) {
            alert("It appears that you aren't asking me a question.");
        }
        //If the question has already been asked, display the appropriate alert.
        else if (previousQuestion && previousQuestion === question) {
            alert("You've already asked that.");
        }
        //If all goes well, then the question will be answered.
        // Set this question as previous question to compare with next time.
        else {
            previousQuestion = question;
            answer = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
        }

    };
    </script>
</div>
```